# El origen de la expresión ¡Qué copado!

Tags: modismos, expresiones, argentina

Me gustaría saber de dónde proviene la expresión argentina ***¡Qué copado!***

Comment: "Copado" no se usa en España, pero sí "copón" ("Me he comprado un coche del copón"--> Me he comprado un coche _muy bueno_). El [origen](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AldNJkG) es el vaso que se usa para contener las hostias consagradas en la misa católica. No sé si hasta cierto punto _copado_ puede ser una corrupción de _copón_.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 - por favor, incluye en tu pregunta una explicación de la expresión.

Comment: _Copado_ en Argentina significa "excelente", "espectacular", "genial".

Comment: Y en Chile _copado_ significa "lleno".

Answer (score 5):

No estoy seguro del origen, pero supongo que aquí el verbo "copar" tiene el sentido de "llenar" (llenar las expectativas, colmar los deseos, satisfacer - todas expresiones relacionadas). De allí "esta persona me copa" ("me complace totalmente"), que luego vino a usarse como expresión enfática de aprobación y encomio.

A partir de esto habría nacido el adjetivo correspondiente : "copado" (que, en tal caso, no es de formación muy correcta; debería ser más bien "copante"...). Pero esto es mera suposición mía.

Answer (score 4):

El significado que más se aproxima es el segundo del DRAE: [Definición de "copado"](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=AjMgS0I), sólo que en este caso el significado es pasivo:

- Estoy **copado** con esa chica (esa chica me **copa**).

[Aquí](http://www.diccionarioargentino.com/term/copado) se puede encontrar una definición sencilla pero precisa del significado activo de "copado" en Argentina, donde también se utiliza para referirse a alguien o algo que provoca entusiasmo.

Se trata, entonces, de una palabra con doble sentido, activo y pasivo, según el contexto:

- ¡Qué chica **copada**! Estoy **copado** con ella.

Existen pares de adjetivos en el idioma donde uno es activo y otro pasivo, por ejemplo: *interesante* e *interesado*. Pero también existen otros casos donde el mismo adjetivo tiene ambos significados, como por ejemplo "aburrido":

- Estoy **aburrido** (pasivo). El libro que estoy leyendo es muy **aburrido** (activo).

Mi teoría es que *copado* ha adquirido su significado activo como una extensión o deformación de su significado pasivo. Sólo es cuestión de que la RAE lo registre.

Comment: La pregunta es muy concisa y puede que también quiera saber del significado, pero así como está ahora pregunta por su origen. Incluir en la respuesta algo de etimología de la palabra sería interesante.

Comment: @fedorqui La etimologìa no es mi fuerte. Sólo me permito especular sobre el posible origen a partir del uso.

Answer (score 1):

Soy argentina y copado no significa lo que dicen.
Alguien copado es alguien muy majo.
Alguien divertido, buena onda

Luego, tambien puede ser:
-Me voy de vacaciones con mis amigas!
-uhh que copado!

O sea, que bueno, que divertido!

Otra: estoy viendo una serie muy copada!
Seria que la serie está buena, que te has enganchado con ella

Answer (score 0):

En Argentina usamos la palabra con un sentido de ponderación, de algo **lleno**, **colmado**, **completo**,  **pletórico**

> [Pletórico](https://dle.rae.es/plet%C3%B3rico?m=form)
>
> 1. adj. Que tiene gran abundancia de algo. Pletórico DE fuerzas.
>    (...)

Al derivarse del verbo [copar](https://dle.rae.es/llenar?m=form) (ocupar o [llenar](https://dle.rae.es/llenar?m=form) (que es igual a `colmar, sobrepasando ciertos requisitos, exigencias o expectativas`) se puede interpretar que ***copado*** surgió como un adjetivo para expresar la cualidad de satisfactoria plenitud de algo o alguien.

De una persona que nos gusta mucho, que nos cae muy bien, decimos que

> es una tipa/tipo muy copada/o

significando el elogio  **llena de algo inusual, destacado o sobresaliente**, **'que lo tiene todo'**, y por tanto, muy agradable y atrayente.

Answer (score 0):

Para añadir algo, los adolescentes ahora utilizan "Copar" para decir "Besar/se"

Copar.
¿Copas?
¿Copamos?